# how to register a dll using MSBuild

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I'm trying to register a DLL on a machine using MS build to avoid having to manually register it every time.  Can anyone point me in the right direction please?
Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using the [MSBuild Community Tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/) you can use the InstallAssembly task

Example:

```
<InstallAssembly AssemblyFiles="Engine.dll;Presenter.dll" />
```

Or:

```
<MSBuild Projects="Project1.csproj;Project2.csproj">
 <Output TaskParameter="TargetOutputs" ItemName="ProjectBinaries" />
</MSBuild>
<InstallAssembly AssemblyFiles="@(ProjectBinaries)" />
```

Comment: oh wow thanks for this, I'll see how it works.  My only concern with this is how will I know whether it works or not?  Obviously I have some code that uses the DLL but is there a way to output of the dll registration worked or not?

Comment: you can use the ShowCallStack="true" property which will print the call stack to the log in case of any exceptions during the installation process.

Comment: and I'm pretty sure that the build will fail if the task is unsuccessfull

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is using the Exec task and call gacutil.exe which is shipped with .NET FX SDK.

So you don't need any additional software.